# C++ Builder 2009 - Cannot focus a disabled or invisible window

Tags: c++, c++builder

I've been **refactoring** an old project. I found when the old programmers tried to use the  `SetFocus()` of `TWinControls` they surrounded them in try/catches with empty catch blocks. Thus swallowing the exceptions.

The default behavior of the program is to set the focus if the control is enabled. In order to do that I created a function which I can pass the `TWinControl` to:

```
void SafeSetFocus(TWinControl *Control)
{
    if(Control->Enabled && Control->Visible)
    {
        Control->SetFocus();
    }
}
```

This code works for most of the program, however I found that in one area that I still get a Debugger Exception of `Cannot focus a disabled or invisible window`.

I thought that the issue might be related to the parent, so I tried the following adjustment:

```
void SafeSetFocus(TWinControl *Control)
{
    if(Control->Enabled && Control->Visible &&
            Control->Parent->Enabled && Control->Parent->Visible)
    {
        Control->SetFocus();
    }
}
```

This changed did not solve the issue. Because of this, I realized that the window may not necessarily be the parent. So my question boils down to:

Is there a way to determine what the window of the `TWinControl` is and check to see if it is visible? This assumes the exception is accurate... otherwise if you know what the issue is, please share your knowledge :)

---

**Additional Troubleshooting Notes, Part 1:**

I've tried to determine the class name of the ParentWindow by the following code:

```
String parentWindowClassName = ((TObject *)(Control->ParentWindow))->ClassName();
MessageDlg("parentWindowClassName: " + parentWindowClassName, mtInformation, TMsgDlgButtons() << mbOK, 0);
```

The first line of code gives an access violation when I run it... any thoughts on a different way to try to determine the info?

**Additional Troubleshooting Notes, Part 2:**

`CanFocus()` with just the control doesn't work. `CanFocus()` for the control and parent doesn't work, see screen shot.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks goes out to @KenWhite for his suggestions in question ( [C++ Builder 2009 - How to Determine if Control's Window is Visible](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15444503/c-builder-2009-how-to-determine-if-controls-window-is-visible/15444976#15444976) )

His suggestions in that question lead me to the answer. Below is the code others might be interested in:

```
#include "winuser.h"

...

void SafeSetFocus(TWinControl *Control)
{
    THandle* hWnd = (THandle *)(Control->ParentWindow);
    bool parentIsVisible = IsWindowVisible(hWnd);

    if(Control->Enabled && Control->Visible && parentIsVisible)
    {
        Control->SetFocus();
    }
}
```

Comment: This is wrong - ParentWindow is a HWND (or THandle), not a THandle*.  You should't hard-cast, and especially not to a pointer type. This was pointed out in your other question, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15444503/c-builder-2009-how-to-determine-if-controls-window-is-visible

Answer (score 3):

There is a much simplier solution - call the `TWinControl::CanFocus()` method before calling `TWinControl::SetFocus()`:

```
void SafeSetFocus(TWinControl *Control)
{
    if (Control->CanFocus())
        Control->SetFocus();
}
```

Comment: I tried CanFocus() as part of my troubleshooting steps. I found that it can replace Control->Enabled and Control->Visible, however it does not solve the exception if the parent is not visible.

Answer (score 0):

Improving on [James Oravec](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1190934/james-oravec)'s [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15444993/563532). I just changed:

```
bool parentIsVisible = IsWindowVisible(hWnd);
```

to:

```
bool parentIsVisible = IsWindowVisible((HWND__*)hWnd);
```