# C++ Builder 2009 - How to Determine if Control's Window is Visible

Tags: c++, winapi, com, c++builder, void-pointers

I have a `TWinControl` and am trying to determine if the parent window is visible.

I see `TWinControl` has a property of `ParentWindow`. The return type of `ParentWindow` is `void *`. So I'm curious if I must cast to a particular type, which would then give me access to check if the window is visible or not.

Does anyone know the type I need to cast to, or another way to accomplish this?

---

**Additional Troubleshooting Notes, Part 1:**

I tried to get the ParentWindows class by:

```
String parentWindowClassName = ((TObject *)(Control->ParentWindow))->ClassName();
```

But this gave an access violation. I also tried casting to TForm, which also gave an access violation, which makes me believe the parent window may be controlled by windows. If so, does anyone know of any trick to check if it is visible? E.g. Any COM tricks or anything?

**Additional Troubleshooting Notes, Part 2:**

The answer to this question may help solve my other question: [C++ Builder 2009 - Cannot focus a disabled or invisible window](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15444418/c-builder-2009-cannot-focus-a-disabled-or-invisible-window)

However the other question may be solved without this approach, which is why I posted a different question.

**Additional Troubleshooting Notes, Part 3:**

Thanks for the extra info Ken. I got my info off code assist:
[image]

However I see your HWND return type from: http://docs.embarcadero.com/products/rad_studio/delphiAndcpp2009/HelpUpdate2/EN/html/delphivclwin32/Controls_TWinControl_ParentWindow.html

That might be the extra info I need... will post a solution if I get it working. Thx.

Comment: You need to show more context. You're not giving any information about what `Control` is - is this related to or an offshoot of [your other question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/15444418/62576)? If so, you should link to it so we know what you're talking about, and if not you need to provide more information about the context you're using here.

Comment: @KenWhite Thanks for the suggestion. The answer to this question would most likely solve the other, however a solution to that question may not necessarily answer this one, which is why I posted a separate question.

Comment: The return type of ['ParentWindow`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE3/en/Vcl.Controls.TWinControl.ParentWindow) isn't `void`. It's `HWND` (window handle). You're typecasting `Control` to `(TObject*)`, and `TObject` doesn't have a `ParentWindow` property. The context is important, though - without the other question to provide definition of what you're doing here, the line of code you posted is absolutely meaningless - it typecasts something called `Control` to some generic `TObject` pointer, and there's no indication of what `Control` might be without context.

Comment: You should probably also use [Control->InheritsFrom(TWinControl)](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE3/en/System.TObject.InheritsFrom) before blindly typecasting it to something else. :-)

Comment: @KenWhite Thanks for all the suggestions... I'm looking forward to figuring out what the final answer is.

Comment: @KenWhite I normally don't blindly cast :) I was trying to determine the type and originally thought it would be of TForm type... but was wrong. Thanks for the suggestion of InheritsFrom it'll be useful in the future.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@KenWhite, your suggestions gave me what I needed, thanks!

The following is the code that solved my problem:

```
#include "winuser.h"

...

void SafeSetFocus(TWinControl *Control)
{
    HWND hWnd = Control->ParentWindow;
    bool parentIsVisible = IsWindowVisible(hWnd);

    if(Control->Enabled && Control->Visible && parentIsVisible)
    {
        Control->SetFocus();
    }
}
```

Comment: `THandle*` is the wrong data type to cast to.  The `ParentWindow` property is an ordinary Win32 API `HWND` instead, no need to type-cast it at all: `HWND hWnd = Control->ParenWindow;`

Comment: HWND* hWnd = (HWND*)Control->ParentWindow; // This works, but without the cast you would receive a compile error of "Cannot convert 'void * const' to void * *'

Comment: `HWND` is already a pointer, there is no need to add an extra layer of indirection. The `ParentWindow` **DOES NOT** return an `HWND*` pointer. It returns a plain `HWND`, like I showed you. Also, `IsWindowVisible()` takes a plain `HWND` as input, **NOT** an `HWND*`. Stop type-casting everything. You are forcing the compiler to ignore errors in your code. `HWND hWnd = Control->ParentWindow; bool parentIsVisible = IsWindowVisible(hWnd);`. Or simply: `bool parentIsVisible = IsWindowVisible(Control->ParentWindow);`

Comment: @RemyLebeau, I edited the answer to remove the errors. The original poster might be confused because some VCL methods - this might be one of them - that return handles are shown in the IDE as returning `void*`. From memory occasionally you do need to hard-cast to the right handle type - but definitely not to a pointer to it :)